# Spring @ContextConfiguration fails to load test context from different project

Tags: java, spring, testing

I am writing Integration tests from my repository project that needs to load the IT test context of my infra project, but for some reason it fails on some weird exception

```
 java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:673)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:480)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:306)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:241)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:70)
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3217)
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3224)
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3224)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3176)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.IgnoredBuilder.runnerForClass(IgnoredBuilder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestMethodReference.<init>(JUnit4TestMethodReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

The same Configuration that i want to add works fine on the Infra project.

Why cant I import that configuration elsewhere?

here is the context configurations:

```
 @ContextConfiguration(  classes = {InfraTestsContextConfiguration.class, RepositoryITContext.class, StandaloneDataSourceConfig.class, TransactionManagerConfig.class, LiquibaseConfig.class},
                   loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class  )
```

And the `InfraTestsContextConfiguration` which i want to load is:

```
 @Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.X.infra"},
excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(pattern = "com.X.infra.spring.InfraContextConfiguration", type = FilterType.REGEX)})
```

Trying to be as clear as i can here because i don't really get this myself

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a test-specific `@Configuration` class from another project is not visible on the classpath. For example, if your `InfraTestsContextConfiguration` is not in the *main* source code folder, then it may not be visible. So, the solution is to make them *visible*, and the way to achieve that depends on your build software (e.g., Maven) or your IDE (e.g., Eclipse).

This sounds similar to the point discussed in the comments in the following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24703689/388980

Comment: seems to me like it might be the same problem but there is no solution... is there no way to share classes in the test folder, seems like something trevial

Comment: Yes, there should be a way to share you test classes, but we'll have to see your exact Eclipse `.classpath` files to assist you with Eclipse. As for Maven, you can use _attached tests_ as described in the Maven reference: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html. You can also search for "maven export test classes" in Google.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out and come back to you but most likely it should solve every thing.